# Add form option in controller

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have a for used too many places in my website :

```
$lot = new Lot();
$form = $this->createForm('logiciel_lot_form', $lot);
```

But, **In only one controller** *(not in form)*, I want add "read_only" in one field. It's possible ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The 'read_only' option is [deprecated and removed in Symfony 3.0](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#read-only).  But you can still accomplish this in a few different ways.  A simple way would be to modify your Twig template for that specific controller:

```
{{ form_widget(form.myfield, {'attr': {'readonly': 'true'}}) }}
```

Another way would be to pass a value to the constructor of your form indicating whether or not the field should have 'read_only' set:

```
class LotType
{
    // defaulted the read only attribute to false here since that is most common
    public function __construct($myFieldReadOnly = false)
    {
        $this->myFieldReadOnly = $myFieldReadOnly;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('myfield', null, array(
                'attr' => array(
                    'read_only' => $this->myFieldReadOnly,
                 )
             ))
        ;
    }
}
```

Then when you create your form you simply pass that option if you need to:

```
// most cases
$form = $this->createForm(new LotType(), $lot);

// case where field needs to have read_only set
$form = $this->createForm(new LotType(true), $lot);
```

As a side note, if you are looking for the field to not be editable at all and have Symfony ignore any submitted value, you might want to look at [setting the disabled attribute](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#disabled) instead.